# Constantly check if an element is on the screen - Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to be always checking if an element is currently on a website. The website is dynamically updating, so I want to check every time it updates, if possible, or just in a while True loop. I have this code right now:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
while True:
    if EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'multiple-choice')):
        print('was mult but not quite')
        if not EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'video-loading-overlay')):
            print("hooray")
            eng = driver.find_element_by_class_name('qquestion')
            print(eng.get_attribute('text'))
            break
```

However, this constantly prints "was mult but not quite" even if there is no element with the class name multiple_choice on screen.

Comment: Is an element with `ID` `video-loading-overlay` still in the DOM even if it's not visible? `presence_of_element_located` will return true if it's in the DOM, even if it's not actually visible. Maybe try `visibility_of_element_located` if you can confirm the overlay is still there, just not visible. I can add this as an answer if that is indeed the situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the below line

```
if not EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'video-loading-overlay')):
```

to

```
if (len(driver.find_elements_by_id('video-loading-overlay'))==0):
```

Comment: I think you ment == instead of = ( but i can be wrong )

Comment: @StyleZ Thanks for letting me know, updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking the element.First check the length count is more than zero and then move on to next element to check the same again.Try the below code.See If this helps.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

while True:
    if len(WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'multiple-choice'))))>0:
        print('was mult but not quite')
        if len(WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, 'video-loading-overlay'))))==0:
            print("hooray")
            eng = driver.find_element_by_class_name('qquestion')
            print(eng.get_attribute('text'))
            break
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: You should add an explanation of what you changed and why it's better.

Comment: @JeffC : Added my explanation.Thanks.